# Can we call two html template file in single lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can we call Two HTML template with different names in LWC? As i have one html file created with LWC and then i creatd one more html file with different.
So can we call that second html file in Single js.

Comment: LWC as of now does not support dynamic component creation via Javascript.